# tips/help handling a form with a excessive amount of options with WordPress and PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently in the beginning state of a plugin for WordPress that creates products with attributes and variations depending on the selected options(shirt style, color, and size). But since there are up to 16 sizes, I can only seem to come up with a way by hand-coding every single option. I know I can create a function

```
function create_product_variation($apparel_selected, $size_selected, $color_selected, $variation_sku, $price){
    // This wil get the id for the 'tshirt' in the taxonomy 'pa_apparel'
    $term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( $product->get_id(), 'tshirt', 'pa_apparel', false );

    // get the full term object
    $term = get_term_by('id', $term_taxonomy_ids[0], 'pa_apparel', OBJECT);

    // Now we will add it as a attribute connected to the product
    $theData = Array(
        'pa_my_attribute'=>Array(
            'name'=> 'pa_apparel',
            'value'=> $term->slug,
            'is_visible' => '1',
            'is_variation' => '1',
            'is_taxonomy' => '1'
        )
    );

    update_post_meta( $product->get_id(),'_product_attributes', $theData);

    // And finally a variation is created
    $variation_post = array(
    'post_title'  => $product->get_title() . ' - ' . $term->name,
    'post_name'   => sanitize_title($product->get_title() . ' ' . $term->name),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_excerpt'=> 'My attribute: ' . $term->name,
    'post_parent' => $product->get_id(),
    'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
    'guid'        => $product->get_permalink(),
    'meta_input'  => array(
        'attribute_pa_apparel' => $term->slug
    )
    );
 
    // Creating the product variation
    $variation_id = wp_insert_post( $variation_post );
 
    $variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );

    ## Set/save all other data
 
    // SKU
    $variation->set_sku(rand(1000000,9999999));
    // Prices
    $variation->set_price( 10 );
    $variation->set_regular_price( 10 );
 
    $variation->set_downloadable(false);
 
    // Stock
    $variation->set_manage_stock(false);
    $variation->set_weight(''); // weight (resetting)
    $variation->save(); // Save the data
}
```

something simple like this where I can plugin variables:

```
function create_product_variation($apparel_selected, $size_selected, $color_selected, $variation_sku, $price){
//blah blah blah
}
```

But is there anything that I may be overlooking that can help handle that many different options without having to hand code 300+ `if($POST_['apparel_size'] == blah && $POST_['apparel_color'] == blah && $POST_['apparel_style'] == blah){ Blah blah run that function }`

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Anything not working with that function you want to create?

Comment: I do not want to write 300+ if statements to handle the form. There is nothing technically wrong with my code, I just want to know if there is any better way to handle forms with a LOT of options than handwriting 300+ if statements or something similar. 

I can create a function as I did above and use if/set but I am still writing out code for each possibility of the form.